# What to pass into sqlite_create_function arbitrary pointer

Tags: c#, c++, sqlite, com

Objective: Bind a regular expression function to the sqlite database myself, since the ADO.NET solution isn't available on Windows Universal apps.

**edit** actually, my real objective is to do a word search on the sqlite database, but the hackish way isn't giving back the results that I need.

Ok, so I'm trying to add on to the sqlite-net c# wrapper for sqlite. And...I have no idea what I'm doing, like, it's meme worthy. This is my first time trying to call a COM anything.

The documentation for the function is here: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html, but what it says for this part is: The fifth parameter is an arbitrary pointer. The implementation of the function can gain access to this pointer using sqlite3_user_data().

I don't think that I want to do anything with it and I can't pass a null. Here's what I have:

```
    public void BindRegex(Regex regex)
    {
        CreateFunction(GetConnection().Handle, "regexp", 1, 2, null, IsMatch, null, null);
    }

    public Func<string, bool> IsMatch = text => regex.IsMatch(text);

    [DllImport("sqlite3.dll", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_create_function", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int CreateFunction(
        IntPtr dbHandle,
        string functionName,
        int numArgs,
        int textEncoding,
        IntPtr pApp,
        IntPtr xFunc,
        IntPtr xStep, // null
        IntPtr xFinal // null
        );
```

Thank you for your help with this.

Comment: `my real objective is to do a word search on the sqlite database` You might be looking for [SQLite full-text-search (FTS) extension](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)

Comment: If by "sqlite-net c# wrapper" you mean [`System.Data.SQlite`](http://system.data.sqlite.org/), then it provides `SQLiteFunction` class for you to implement user-defined functions.

Comment: In any case, the fifth parameter to `sqlite3_create_function` can happily be `NULL`. What makes you believe otherwise?

Comment: I tried using FTS, which was fast for the inner query, but since it was being used in a nested select, my query time went from 1-2s to 5-8, sometimes 13s. Unfortunately, since I'm making a Windows Universal app, I don't have access to System.Data. And in regards to why it couldn't be null, it may have been a VS-being-silly thing, but it told me that I couldn't pass in null. I'll try again.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is that you need a delegate to declare your callback pointer, like this.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void UserFunctionCallback(IntPtr context, int nvalues,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)]IntPtr[] values);
```

Inside the function you have to use more of the Sqlite API to retrieve argument values and set the return value. The code looks something like this.

```
  var svalues = new string[nvalues];
  for (int x = 0; x < nvalues; ++x)
    svalues[x - 0] = sqlite3_value_text(values[x]);

  var ret = [do something here];
  sqlite3_result_text(context, ret, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

That's all the hard stuff. The rest is just detail.